# How to get columns of DBF file in my VC++ application

Tags: visual-c++, odbc, foxpro

I have problem to Get columns of DBF file in my vc++ application.

I used SQLColumns() to get Columns List.

but it giving SQL_NO_DATA as result.

what can i do, it happens only for One DBF file. if i create sample DBF file it perfectly worked,

Please give me suggestion,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using ODBC. The VFP ODBC driver works only with VFP 6 and earlier data files. Maybe the file you're having trouble with was created using features added in a later version of VFP?